# How To Get WordPress Categories Link List?

Tags: functions, categories, sitemap

I am trying to make a custom sitemap for my WordPress blogs categories. For that I added the below code in my functions.php file and when I save it, my Blog goes white. Nothing is showing up. I removed this code by going through FTP and then all got again fine.

Now I want to make and use this code. Now can anyone help me out to fix this code?

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- *
 *  Custom Dynamic XML Sitemap Generator For Categories
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
add_action("publish_post", "cat_create_sitemap");
add_action("publish_page", "cat_create_sitemap");
function cat_create_sitemap() {
  $categoriesForSitemap = get_categories(array(
    'hide_empty' => 0, 
    depth => 0, 
    'hierarchical' => false
  ));

  $sitemap = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
  $sitemap .= '<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sitemap-style.xsl"?>';
  $sitemap .= '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';

  foreach($categoriesForSitemap as $category) {
    setup_postdata($category);
    $categorydate = explode(" ", $category->category_modified);
    $sitemap .= '<url>'.
      '<loc>'. get_permalink($category->ID) .'</loc>'.
      '<priority>1</priority>'.
      '<lastmod>'. $categorydate[0] .'</lastmod>'.
      '<changefreq>daily</changefreq>'.
    '</url>';
  }
  $sitemap .= '</urlset>';
  $fp = fopen(ABSPATH . "custom-cat-sitemap.xml", 'w');
  fwrite($fp, $sitemap);
  fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fist error I see is a syntax error:

```
depth => 0
```

should be

```
"depth" => 0
```

Second error is that you are using a category object like a post object. None of these lines will work:

There is no post data to setup. Remove this line:

```
setup_postdata($category);
```

A category object has no category_modified property. Maybe you need the date of the last published post on the category (this is another question)???

```
//Not valid property
$category->category_modified;
```

`get_permalink()` is for posts, for categories use `get_category_link()` instead. Also, $category->ID is not a valid property of a category object, use $category->term_id instead:

```
//Incorrect
get_permalink($category->ID);

//Correct
get_category_link($category->term_id);
```

Comment: Thanks. You mentioned the right thing and all is working now perfectly. Yes, I want to add the date of the last published post on the category so for this I have to ask other question or you can give answer me here too?

Comment: Ask aother question, it is better to maintain things clear. Make a research first, it is very probably that similar question was made before.